# Load enums through FindClass in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have an enum in Java like this:

```
  public enum Status {
    NOT_STARTED(0),
    STARTED(1),
    DONE(2);

    private int value;

    private Status(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Status fromValue(int value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return NOT_STARTED;
            case 1:
                return STARTED;
            case 2:
                return DONE;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can not load this enum through FindClass while accessing it through JNI. Basically, I have an integer in c++ which I want to convert to enum using the static method `fromValue` defined in enum. I have checked the class path multiple times and it is correct. I am unable to understand the reason that why it fails to find that class. The exception thrown is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add the relevant C++ code to the question.

Comment: If Status is an inner class, use `com.qq.package.ParentClass$Status`